# javascript to php and viceversa communicate

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays, ip

I am trying to write a plug-in for firefox which would fetch all the domains from the links of  the current site and display their IP addresses.
for that I have written js code containing "domians". And simple php script:

```
<?php
$ip = gethostbyname('www.example.com');

echo $ip;
?>
```

now i have to pass this "domains" array to php and return the ip values to js code in order to display the domains with ip(s).how can i do this?
I heard that ajax, json can do this. Is there is any other possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, PHP is executed server side. This means that when the user load the plug-in/page/content, the PHP is executed and done with. This being said, JavaScript is executed Client side, meaning it can be executed during the page load, before the page load and after the page load. Unfortunately this means that you cannot pass JavaScript variables to PHP without using AJAX or going to another page.

The way you would pass information from JS to PHP would be by receiving the data you need, then making an Ajax request to a PHP script that would perform some action and then return some value. If that's what you want to do, then there are tutorials/many questions that will help you in doing that.

To pass from PHP to JS, you can do something like:

```
<script>
    var JavascriptVariable = <?php echo $PHPVariable ?>;
</script>
```

But this might be bad practice, I am unsure.